# curve fitting by curve_fit from scipy in Python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit my data with an exponential function

```py
import numpy as np

def exponentional(k, alpha, k0, c):
    return k0 * np.exp(k *-alpha) + c
```

I used `curve_fit` from scipy.optimize,

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
uniq_deg = [2,...,103,..,203,...,307,...,506] 
normalized_deg_dist = [0.99,...,0.43,..0.12,..,0.04,..., 0.01]
           
            
popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponentional, uniq_deg, normalized_deg_dist, 
                       p0 = [1,0.00001,1,1], maxfev = 6000)
           
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
             
ax.semilogy(uniq_deg, normalized_deg_dist, 'bo', label = 'Real data') 
ax.semilogy(uniq_deg,[exponentional(d,*popt) for d in uniq_deg], 'r-', label = 'Fit') 
ax.set_xlabel('Degree' ) 
ax.set_ylabel('1-CDF degree') 
ax.legend(loc='best')
ax.set_title(f'Degree distribution in {city}')
plt.show()
```

Resulting in:

[image]

It does not look like a good fit.

Where I am wrong?

Comment: I would suggest you to use sklearn. It makes everything simple.

Comment: Can you post the dataset? Also, you could try to transform the model into log-space and do the fit there (which is then just a linear fit); that sometimes can help to get better results.

Comment: @VinayakMikkal I am sorry, but if you do not understand what is going wrong from a math point of view, changing the python package is not the solution.

Comment: Hy Maryam, this is probably a quite good fit. You are fitting in linear space. As a consequence the errors on the scale of 1 are by far more important than the errors on the scale of 10e-3, especially as the fit does check the square of those errors. Therefore, all the data below 1e-2 actually does not matter. It seems that your fit puts `c<0` such that you get this divergence on logarithmic scale. Does your model actually require a `c`? can it be negative or can you be sure that `c>=0`? Note, if you fit your data in log-space, as suggested by @Cleb you change the weighting logarithmic.

Comment: It is a huge number of the array. should I copy and paste here? @Cleb

Comment: Or just a subset, like each 1000th data point or so.

Comment: uniq_deg = [2,...,103,..,203,...,307,...,506] and normalized_deg_dist = [0.99,...,0.43,..0.12,..,0.04,..., 0.01] @Cleb

Comment: please put it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I did not use  `curve_fit`. I used the definition of the exponential fit from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html

and also I need to fit some other data by power-law I did the same.

```
    #%%
def fit_powerlaw(xs, ys):
    S_lnx_lny = 0.0
    S_lnx_S_lny = 0.0
    S_lny = 0.0
    S_lnx = 0.0
    S_lnx2 = 0.0
    S_ln_x_2 = 0.0
    n = len(xs)
    for (x,y) in zip(xs, ys):
        S_lnx += np.log(x)
        S_lny += np.log(y)
        S_lnx_lny += np.log(x) * np.log(y)
        S_lnx_S_lny = S_lnx * S_lny
        S_lnx2 += np.power(np.log(x),2)
        S_ln_x_2 = np.power(S_lnx,2)
    #end
    b = (n * S_lnx_lny - S_lnx_S_lny ) / (n * S_lnx2 - S_ln_x_2)
    a = (S_lny - b * S_lnx)  / (n)
    return (np.exp(a), b)
#%%
def fit_exp(xs, ys):
    S_x2_y = 0.0
    S_y_lny = 0.0
    S_x_y = 0.0
    S_x_y_lny = 0.0
    S_y = 0.0
    for (x,y) in zip(xs, ys):
        S_x2_y += x * x * y
        S_y_lny += y * np.log(y)
        S_x_y += x * y
        S_x_y_lny += x * y * np.log(y)
        S_y += y
    #end
    a = (S_x2_y * S_y_lny - S_x_y * S_x_y_lny) / (S_y * S_x2_y - S_x_y * S_x_y)
    b = (S_y * S_x_y_lny - S_x_y * S_y_lny) / (S_y * S_x2_y - S_x_y * S_x_y)
    return (np.exp(a), b)
```

[image]

[image]

First graph for exponential fitting and second for power law.
I think the result is convincing.